# Receive messages continuously using udpClient

Tags: c#, udpclient

I was looking for the best solution to receive and process messages via `UdpClient` class in `C#`. Does anyone have any solutions for this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What do you not like about it/make you believe there is a "better" solution?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Try this code :

```
//Client uses as receive udp client
UdpClient Client = new UdpClient(Port);

try
{
     Client.BeginReceive(new AsyncCallback(recv), null);
}
catch(Exception e)
{
     MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
}

//CallBack
private void recv(IAsyncResult res)
{
    IPEndPoint RemoteIpEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 8000);
    byte[] received = Client.EndReceive(res, ref RemoteIpEndPoint);

    //Process codes

    MessageBox.Show(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(received));
    Client.BeginReceive(new AsyncCallback(recv), null);
}
```

Comment: +1: A couple of notes. First, it's probably not a good idea to call `MessageBox.Show` for error handling, especially in an async callback. But I'll assume you just meant that as, "for example." Second, you probably want to issue the next `BeginReceive` immediately after calling `EndReceive` -- *before* processing the item. Otherwise you can miss messages that arrive while you're processing. Of course, then your async callback has to be re-entrant (i.e. thread safe), but then it already should be.

Comment: is this code work for multiple clients which send request asynchronously.i m stuck in same issue where i have to write the code for multiple client.here my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32837887/udp-client-server

Comment: What is `recv`?

Comment: private void recv(IAsyncResult res)

Comment: recv is shorthand for receive.

Comment: recv is the method private void recv(IAsyncResult res) should really have been private void Recv(IAsyncResult ar) but to each their own.

Comment: @JimMischel thank you very much for bringing up the re-entrancy issue. I did receive doubles of the same packet in some cases, sometimes even incomplete packets until I protected my EndReceive callback against re-entrancy.

Comment: The new async and await methods are so much better than the old way described here.

Answer (score 22):

For newer methods using TAP instead of Begin/End method you can use the following in .Net 4.5

Quite simple!

### Asynchronous Method

```
    private static void UDPListener()
    {
        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            using (var udpClient = new UdpClient(11000))
            {
                string loggingEvent = "";
                while (true)
                {
                    //IPEndPoint object will allow us to read datagrams sent from any source.
                    var receivedResults = await udpClient.ReceiveAsync();
                    loggingEvent += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receivedResults.Buffer);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

### Synchronous Method

As appose to the `asynchronous` method above, this can be also implemented in `synchronous` method in a very similar fashion:

```
    private static void UDPListener()
    {
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            using (var udpClient = new UdpClient(11000))
            {
                string loggingEvent = "";
                while (true)
                {
                    //IPEndPoint object will allow us to read datagrams sent from any source.
                    var remoteEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
                    var receivedResults = udpClient.Receive(ref remoteEndPoint);
                    loggingEvent += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receivedResults);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Yes, this probably runs. But consider an environment such as Unity 3D where you do not have multitasking / multithreading. What do you do in this case?

Comment: is there any equivalent for this Task.Run in .net 3.5?

Comment: @Slesa Late response but you can use multitasking/multithreading in Unity. You just need to access Unity stuff on main thread, everything else can be done on other threads.

Comment: any idea why .net is missing IPEndPoint from ReceiveAsync method? how would you send a message back to the sender?

Comment: @scape it will be in the result UdpReceiveResult->RemoteEndPoint.
in a synchronous method, it is not in vain that the RemoteEndPoint parameter is passed through "ref"