# C# application simply not receiving UDP data

Tags: c#, udp, ethernet

I am trying to do something very simple that does not work: With my C# application I simply want to listen for UDP packages on a specific port. With Wireshark I can see very well that the packages that I desire are received perfectly fine (CRC and everything ok).

However, none of the codes I found on internet work. For example this one failes as well:

```
    private  void ReceiveAsync()
    {

        UdpClient Client = new UdpClient(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 51200));

        try
        {
            Client.BeginReceive(new AsyncCallback(OnReceive), null);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
        }
    }

    private static void OnReceive(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Simply to tell you that something was received on the port");
    }
```

There are two ethernet network cards installed. Maybe this can be a problem? But even if I specify the IP address specifically it would not change anything.

```
            UdpClient Client = new UdpClient(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("10.0.0.2"), 51200));
```

I would be very happy about any ideas that could solve this problem. Thank you very much!

Comment: If this doesn't get answered in 24h, I'll set a bounty.

Comment: `OnReceive` will not be called in the UI context (it will be running on a ThreadPool thread), so displaying a MessageBox might not be reliable. Replace that with Debug.WriteLine and run in the debugger and repost.

Comment: You call BeginReceive() but never EndReceive() ?
I think you need to pass the Client object in the OnReceiveMethod to call client.EndReceive() there

Comment: There are differences between MSDN example and your code:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.udpclient.beginreceive.aspx  (most notable the `UdpState`)

Comment: I tried it with Debug.WriteLine, but still nothing

Comment: Unfortunatelly, it would still not work...in the meantime I just tried it with a simple Java application and there it works perfectly fine

Answer (score 2):

The code is fine and working - I have tested it.

You need to wait for received data, `Client` object exist only in `ReceiveAsync`

Try adding `Thread.Sleep(10000)`

**Edit:**
`Thread.Sleep(1000)`  is not good practice since it block the thread.
it's depend on the problem/case that you are trying to solve. you may have some kind of TCP engine that handle multiple connection ,or data processing so you can say data on buffer for some other thread to work on.

If you share the problem that you are trying to solve , maybe can give better answer
Also can see the code example from [MSDN - UdpClient.BeginReceive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.udpclient.beginreceive.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for having tested it! I let the code run as part of a Forms application, so I will not need to let the application sleep.

Comment: so I think you need to save `Client` as member - see my comment in the answer

Answer (score 0):

I found this thread in here

[Receive messages continuously using udpClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7266101/receive-messages-continuously-using-udpclient)

May be this helps.

1. you should really not show a message box, think about a debug output.
2. save your input directly after receiving, to avoid blocking the network.

Comment: By now I tried two code versions that both seem to receive UDP packages perfectly fine when the UDP packages were sent for example from another application. The packages I want to receive though, they are sent to the PC from an FPGA board... Does anyone of you maybe have an idea why those are ignored instead? According to Wireshark they are perfectly well formed...