# UDP server and UDP client

Tags: udp

I have problem. Why my client cannot recieve data from server? Server is recieving data from client without problems. Is it because my client is not connected on my server client. Have someone any idea? And sorry for my English, I am from Czech Republic. :)

This is my UDP client:

```
    UdpClient client;
    public IPAddress serverIP = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        client = new UdpClient();
    }

    public void SendData()
    {
        client.Connect(serverIP, 3000);
        byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Hi, I'm new client.");
        client.Send(data, data.Length);
        DoListening();
    }
    public void DoListening()
    {
        IPEndPoint adress = new IPEndPoint(serverIP, 3000);
        byte[] receivedbytes = client.Receive(ref adress);
        string recieved = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receivedbytes);

        MessageBox.Show("Recieved: " + recieved);
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SendData();
    }
```

This is my UDP server:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Thread listening = new Thread(new ThreadStart(DoListening));
        listening.Start();
    }
    public void ClientThread(Object adress)
    {
        IPEndPoint ip = adress as IPEndPoint;
        UdpClient client = new UdpClient();
        client.Connect(ip);
        byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("No nazdar");
        client.Send(data, data.Length);
        MessageBox.Show("Sending data..");
    }
    public void DoListening()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            UdpClient client = null;
            client = new UdpClient(3000);
            IPEndPoint host = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
            MessageBox.Show("Listening");
            byte[] receivedbytes = client.Receive(ref host);
            string recieved = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receivedbytes);
            MessageBox.Show("Client " + host.Address.ToString() + " conected. Message: " + recieved);
            new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(ClientThread)).Start(host);
            Console.WriteLine("Doslo k vyjimce z duvodu : {0}", ex.SocketErrorCode);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16919469/c-sharp-application-simply-not-receiving-udp-data#comment24423243_16919469

Answer (score 0):

no sure but I think you are trying to connect to localhost

```
UdpClient client;
public IPAddress serverIP = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    client = new UdpClient();
}

public void SendData()
{
    client.Connect(serverIP, 3000);
```

You are connecting to yourself . You need to change 127.0.0.1 for the actual server ip address...

////I am assuming that the client and the server are not on the same device.

Comment: they are :-( (Very old topic)

Answer (score 0):

You may like [route_io](https://github.com/Taymindis/route_io), it is c/c++ based library, it make udp/tcp/http all in one single instance. You just get the source and example to do whatever you want for your project. Simple Example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include "route_io.h"

void init_instance(void *arg);
void read_handler(rio_request_t *req);

void init_instance(void *arg) {
  printf("%s\n", "start instance");
}

void read_handler(rio_request_t *req) {
  printf("preparing echo back %.*s\n", (int) (req->in_buff->end - req->in_buff->start), req->in_buff->start);
  rio_write_output_buffer_l(req, req->in_buff->start, (req->in_buff->end - req->in_buff->start));
}

void on_conn_close_handler(rio_request_t *req) {
  printf("%s\n", "connection closing");
}

int main(void) {

  rio_instance_t * instance = rio_create_routing_instance(24, NULL, NULL);
  rio_add_udp_fd(instance, 12345/*port*/, read_handler, on_conn_close_handler);
  rio_add_tcp_fd(instance, 3232/*port*/, read_handler, 64, on_conn_close_handler);

  rio_start(instance);

  return 0;
}
```