# C#.Net UdpClient Receive Event

Tags: c#, .net, udpclient

I'd like to find out if there is any way I could somehow fire an event when my UdpClient receives data? (System.Net.Sockets.UdpClient)

I tried overriding it's UdpClient.Receive but I can't according to [**this**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ebca9ah3.aspx) because overridable members have to be marked virtual or abstract.

The way I am currently doing it is by running a TimerCallback on Threading.Timer at specific intervals to fetch my data but I'd prefer to receive incoming data as it arrives instead of fetching it repeatedly.

Any suggestions, recommendations or pointers as to how I can do this or do I HAVE TO manually receive on intervals?

Comment: I believe UdpClient.Receive method blocks the current thread until it receives data?

Comment: What does this have to do with ASP.NET?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Receive messages continuously using udpClient](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7266101/receive-messages-continuously-using-udpclient)

Answer (score 6):

Overriding the `Receive` method wouldn't help you anyway - it's not a method that's called when the UDP client receives data, it's a method *you* call when you want to wait for incomming data.

However, the `Receive` method blocks. This means that you don't really have to check at intervals - you can simply check in an (almost) infinite loop. Just do it in a different thread.

```
void Loop(CancellationToken token)
{
  var remoteEP = default(IPEndPoint);

  while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
  {
    var data = client.Receive(ref remoteEP);

    yourForm.Invoke(DataReceived, data);
  }
}
```

And of course, since this is simple I/O, there's no need to occupy a thread to do this - you can use asynchronous I/O:

```
public Task Loop(CancellationToken token)
{
  using (UdpClient client = new UdpClient(80))
  {
    while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
      var data = await client.ReceiveAsync();

      // Process the data as needed
    }
  }
}
```

In a winforms or WPF application, this will work pretty much automagically - you'll just use this code in say `btnStart_Click` event handler, and it will keep your UI responsive while waiting for data in the background; and whenever the data gets back, it will execute the rest of the code (`Process the data as needed`) on the UI thread - no need to create any threads manually or handle dispatching.

Of course, it's somewhat tricky to handle termination, but that's always tricky with UDP - basically, you'd either have to use the more manual way that supports cancellation (`ReceiveAsync` is just a wrapper for `BeginReceive` and `EndReceive` which don't support cancellation), or you'd use the old trick of setting the cancellation token and then sending a 0-length data packet to yourself (causing the `Receive` call to end and return a zero-length byte array).

Comment: You have to specify an endpoint with UDPClient when using .Receive

Comment: @VoteCoffee Right, my bad. I fixed that :)

Answer (score 3):

You can also use Rx Extensions to receive the data.

Wrap the `ReceiveAsync` from the `UpdClient` in an `Observable.FromAsync` and subscribe to the observable.

```
UdpClient client = new UdpClient(..., ...);
var obs = Observable.FromAsync(client.ReceiveAsync);
var sub = obs.Subscribe(...);
```

Answer (score 2):

UdpClient.Receive blocks the execution until it receives data from the endpoint. But there is an asyncronous alternative, UdpClient.BeginReceive. It's not exactly an event, but works in a similar way and you can encapsulate it and fire your own events. The documentation (with code example) can be found here: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.udpclient.beginreceive(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.udpclient.beginreceive%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)