C# UDP client and server, I don't understand using async and communication between two scripts
I never tried UDP before. The synchronous version works, but I need it async.
The client should connect the factory, send like a passphrase, server compares that, too. After that the server should send a datapack (remote reset). After that everything should close. The server should still listen to other connection requests.
I tried a task list but couldn't make it work. I can't even make the async work. Any tips?
This script is my newest client script:
class UDPClient : IDisposable
{
    public static bool messageReceived = false;

    public const int listenPort = 11000;

    public byte[] firstMessage = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("I heard you");
    public byte[] firstCond = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Send Login Data");

    public AsyncCallback checkConnectionCB = new AsyncCallback(CheckConnection); 

    public struct UdpState
    {
        public UdpClient listenerMaster;   //u
        public IPEndPoint customerMaster;       // e
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        UDPClient start = new UDPClient();
        start.StartListener();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
 
    // Send message to customer here (eg Login)
    // send data package if ok
    public void StartListener()
    {
        UdpClient listener = new UdpClient(); 
        IPEndPoint customer = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, listenPort); 

        listener.Connect(customer);
        listener.DontFragment = true;

        Console.WriteLine("Connecting to factory (StartListener)"); 

        // Wait for customer ip and port
        // save customer ip and port so listener can open new line
        listener.Connect(customer);

        Console.WriteLine("Connecting to customer"); 

        try
        {
            listener.BeginSend(firstMessage, firstMessage.Length, checkConnectionCB, firstCond);
        }
        catch (SocketException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }
    }

    public static void CheckConnection(IAsyncResult resultConnection)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("CheckConnection IAsyncREsult sollte kommen");
    }
} 

I tried a task list but that wouldn't see the connection. I just can't wrap my head around on how that should work and how to make it work...
EDIT:
changed my code (server/factory side), still got some questions
Tried the factory side now. It should listen to any IP later. Now I don't have an entry point besides using static async void Main().
I fell like there are major mistakes but somehow I managed it, that Visual Studio doesn't give many errors.
My questions are:

How do I ell it, that the Main() method is the starting point? It worked with my old code somehow...

How do I let it run, when someone contacts it and where should I open another listener so it can receive another request while working on the first one?

Does it open different listeners or is it always the same for the Task list?
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Net.Sockets;
  using System.Net;
  using System.Text;
  using System.Threading.Tasks;
  using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
  using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
  using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

  namespace Factory
  {
      // CHANGE: Customer IP to Any IP
      // CHANGE: customer Port to Any Port
      class FactoryUDP : UdpClient, IDisposable
      {
          public bool IsCompleted { get; }

          public const int listenPort = 11000;

          public static bool isConnected;
          public static bool messageReceived;

          public string testData = "UserName PassWord";

          public byte[] message1 = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Please write user name and password, separated with one space and hit enter.");
          public object? sendOne;

          public IAsyncResult? loginAsyncResult;


          static async void Main()
          {
              Console.WriteLine("Starting Main");

              FactoryUDP start = new FactoryUDP();
              start.RemoteReset();
              // await/ return / something;
          }

          public struct UdpState
          {
              public UdpClient u;     //listener
              public IPEndPoint e;    //customer
          }

          /*
          public void Dispose()
          {
              throw new NotImplementedException();
          }
          */

          public async Task RemoteReset()
          {

              var connectionTask = ConnectCustomer();
              var loginTask = LoginRequest();
              var sendRemoteTask = SendRemoteReset();
              var closeTask = CloseEverything();

              await connectionTask;
              await loginTask;
              await sendRemoteTask;

              var remoteTasks = new List<Task> { connectionTask, loginTask, sendRemoteTask };
              while (remoteTasks.Count > 0)
              {
                  Task finishedTask = await Task.WhenAny(remoteTasks);
                  if (finishedTask == connectionTask)
                  {
                      Console.WriteLine("ConnectionTask finished");
                  }
                  else if (finishedTask == loginTask)
                  {
                      Console.WriteLine("LoginTask finished");
                  }
                  else if (finishedTask == sendRemoteTask)
                  {
                      Console.WriteLine("Send remote Task finished");
                  }
                  await finishedTask;

                  Console.WriteLine($"Task isCompleted state: {IsCompleted}");
                  await Task.WhenAll(remoteTasks.ToArray());
                  // remoteTasks.Remove(finishedTask);
                  // Task list: wait for all remoteTasks and then CloseEverything();
              }

              async Task ConnectCustomer()
              {
                  UdpClient u = new UdpClient(listenPort);
                  IPEndPoint e = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, listenPort);

                  u.Connect(e);
                  u.DontFragment = true;

                  isConnected = true;

                  u.BeginReceive(ReceiveCallback1, e);        // EndReceive in ReceiveCallback1
                  Console.WriteLine("BeginReceive - ReceiveCallback1 in ConnectCustomer");

                  u.BeginSend(message1, message1.Length, SendCallback1, sendOne); // EndSend in SendCallback1
                  Console.WriteLine("BeginSend Message1 - SendCallback1 in ConnectCustomer");

                  // when connected to customer add a new listener to listen for other customers?

                  await ConnectCustomer();
                  await LoginRequest();
                  //await LoginCompare();
                  await SendRemoteReset();

              }

              async Task LoginRequest()
              {
                  // begin receive, user name and password separated with space?

                  UdpClient u = ((UdpState)loginAsyncResult.AsyncState).u;
                  IPEndPoint e = ((UdpState)loginAsyncResult.AsyncState).e;

                  UdpState s = new UdpState();
                  s.e = e;
                  s.u = u;

                  u.BeginReceive(new AsyncCallback (ReceiveCallback2), s);
                  byte[] receiveLoginData = u.EndReceive(loginAsyncResult, ref e);
                  string receiveLoginDataString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receiveLoginData);
                  Console.WriteLine($"Received Login data: {receiveLoginDataString}");

                  // separate string to user name (space) password        receiveLoginDataString
                  //What to do with the login data? write in j son?

                  if (testData == receiveLoginDataString)
                  {
                      await SendRemoteReset();
                      Console.WriteLine("Successfully compared testData with receivedString, awaiting SendRemoteReset");
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      await CloseEverything();
                      Console.WriteLine("Failed to compare testData with received LoginData. Awaiting CloseEverything");
                  }

                  //return Task.;
                  await LoginRequest();
              }


              static async Task SendRemoteReset()
              {
                  Console.WriteLine("SendRemoteReset here (datapack)");
                  //send remote reset data pack and CloseEverything()
                  await Task.Delay(2);
              }

              static async Task CloseEverything()
              {
                  isConnected = false;

                  Console.WriteLine("CloseEverything here. Waiting for Task.Delay(330)");

                  await Task.Delay(300);
                  // Close everything and start another listener for customers
              }


              static async void ReceiveCallback1(IAsyncResult ar1)
              {
                  UdpClient u = ((UdpState)ar1.AsyncState).u;
                  IPEndPoint e = ((UdpState)ar1.AsyncState).e;

                  byte[] receiveBytes = u.EndReceive(ar1, ref e);
                  string receiveString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receiveBytes);

                  Console.WriteLine($"Received: {receiveString}");
                  messageReceived = true;
                  Console.WriteLine("Setting messageReceived to true");

                  return;
              }
              // public delegate here?

              async void SendCallback1(IAsyncResult? sendOne)
              {
                  UdpClient u = ((UdpState)sendOne.AsyncState).u;
                  IPEndPoint e = ((UdpState)sendOne.AsyncState).e;

                  u.EndSend(sendOne);
                  Console.WriteLine("EndSend ind SendCallback1 here");

                  await LoginRequest();
              }

              async void ReceiveCallback2(IAsyncResult? loginAsyncResult)
              {
                  UdpClient u = ((UdpState)loginAsyncResult.AsyncState).u;
                  IPEndPoint e = ((UdpState)loginAsyncResult.AsyncState).e;

              byte[] receiveLoginData = u.EndReceive(loginAsyncResult, ref e);
              string receiveLoginDataString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receiveLoginData);
              Console.WriteLine($"Received Login data: {receiveLoginDataString}");

              return;

              // go to LoginRequest from here?
          }


      }

  }

}


edit 11 july 2024
I rewrote the code again, learned again a lot but still can'T make the server und client communicate with each other...
server side:
    class FactoryUDP : UdpClient, IDisposable
    {
        // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7266101/receive-messages-continuously-using-udpclient
        public bool IsCompleted { get; }
    
        public byte[] factoryIP = new byte[] { 127, 0, 0, 1 }; // line 83/84                    //ToDo.MG rewrite for any IP and remove
        public const int listenPort = 11000;                                    //ToDo.MG rewrite for any IP and remove
    
        public static bool isConnected;
        public static bool messageReceived;
    
        public string testData = "UserName PassWord";                           //ToDo.MG rewrite and remove
        public string? receiveLoginDataString;
    
        public byte[] message1 = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Please write user name and password, separated with one space and hit enter.");   //ToDo.MG rewrite and remove
    
        public object? sendOne;
        public object? loginAsyncResult;
        public object? cusConnSuccess;
    
        //private static bool IsNotNull1([NotNullWhen(true)] object? cusConnSucc) => cusConnSucc != null;
        //private static bool IsNotNull2([NotNullWhen(true)] object? sendOne) => sendOne != null;
    
        static void Main()
        {
            FactoryUDP start = new FactoryUDP();
            start.MainAsync().Wait();
        }
        public async Task MainAsync()
        {
            UdpClient uMaster = new UdpClient(listenPort);
            IPEndPoint eMaster = new IPEndPoint(new IPAddress(factoryIP), listenPort);
    
            var connectionTask = ConnectCustomer();
            var loginTask = LoginRequest();
            var sendRemoteTask = SendRemoteReset();
            var closeTask = CloseEverything();
    
            await connectionTask;
            await loginTask;
            await sendRemoteTask;
            await closeTask;
    
            var remoteTasks = new List<Task> { connectionTask, loginTask, sendRemoteTask, closeTask };
            while (remoteTasks.Count > 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Task List here");
                Task finishedTask = await Task.WhenAny(remoteTasks);
                if (finishedTask == connectionTask)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("ConnectionTask finished");
                }
                else if (finishedTask == loginTask)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("LoginTask finished");
                }
                else if (finishedTask == sendRemoteTask)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Send remote Task finished");
                }
                else if (finishedTask == closeTask)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Send close Task finished");
                }
                await finishedTask;
    
                Console.WriteLine($"Task isCompleted state: {IsCompleted}");
                await Task.WhenAll();
            }
    
    
            async void ReceiveCallback1(IAsyncResult cusConnSucc)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("BeginReceive - ReceiveCallback1 in ConnectCustomer");
                isConnected = true;
    
                byte[] receiveBytes = uMaster.EndReceive(cusConnSucc, ref eMaster);
                string receiveString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receiveBytes);
                Console.WriteLine($"Received in ReceiveCallback1: {receiveString}");
    
                bool connectMessage = receiveBytes.Equals(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Factory! Listen!"));
                Console.WriteLine($"Received bytes from Gripper: {connectMessage}");
    
                if (connectMessage == true && isConnected)
                {
                    messageReceived = true;
                    Console.WriteLine("Setting messageReceived to true (only if isConnected is also true).");
                    // AsyncCallback callbackCustomerConnect = new AsyncCallback(LoginRequest);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Something went wrong with compare connectMessage");
                    await CloseEverything();
                }
                cusConnSucc.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();
            }
    
            async void SendCallback1(IAsyncResult sendOne)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("BeginSend Message1 - SendCallback1 in ConnectCustomer");
    
                uMaster.EndSend(sendOne);
                Console.WriteLine("EndSend in SendCallback1 here");
    
                sendOne.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();
            }
    
            async void ReceiveCallback2(IAsyncResult? loginAsyncResult)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("BeginReceive - Callback 2 in LoginRequest");
    
                byte[] receiveLoginData = uMaster.EndReceive(loginAsyncResult, ref eMaster);
                string receiveLoginDataString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receiveLoginData);
    
                Console.WriteLine($"Received Login data: {receiveLoginDataString}");
    
                loginAsyncResult.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();
            }
    
            async Task ConnectCustomer()
            {
                uMaster.Connect(eMaster);
    
                Console.WriteLine("Task ConnectCustomer BeginReceive, BeginSend, BeginReceive which are just laying here");
                uMaster.BeginReceive(ReceiveCallback1, cusConnSuccess);
    
                uMaster.BeginSend(message1, message1.Length, SendCallback1, sendOne);
    
                uMaster.BeginReceive(ReceiveCallback2, loginAsyncResult);
    
                await ConnectCustomer();
            }
    
            async Task LoginRequest()
            {
                bool login = receiveLoginDataString.Equals(testData);
                if (login == true)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("login = true, next is SendRemoteReset");
                    await SendRemoteReset();
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("LoginRequest, login false");
                    await CloseEverything();
                }
            }
    
            async Task SendRemoteReset()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("SendRemoteReset here (data pack), now TaskDelay(300) in SendRemoteTask");
                await Task.Delay(300);
            }
    
            async Task CloseEverything()
            {
                isConnected = false;
                Console.WriteLine("CloseEverything here. Waiting for Task.Delay(600)");
                await Task.Delay(600);
                Console.WriteLine("Closing Everything last line.");
                Console.WriteLine("Continue with any Key here, so the program stops for a moment");
                Console.ReadKey(); // just so it won't repeat all the time
            }
        }
    }

and client
    class GripperUDP : UdpClient, IDisposable
    {
        public bool IsCompleted { get; }
    
        public static bool isConnected;
    
    
        object sendFirst;
        object receiveOne;
        object logDataState;
    
        public const int listenPort = 11001;
        public byte[] factoryIP = new byte[] { 127, 0, 0, 1 };
    
        public string compareLoginData = "UserName PassWord"; 
    
        public byte[] connectMessage = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Factory! Listen!");
    
        static void Main()
        {
            GripperUDP start = new GripperUDP();
            start.MainAsync().Wait();
        }
    
        public async Task MainAsync()
        {
            UdpClient uMaster = new UdpClient(listenPort);
            IPEndPoint eMaster = new IPEndPoint(new IPAddress(factoryIP), listenPort);
    
            var connectionTask = ConnectFactory();
            var receiveRemoteTask = ReceiveRemoteReset();
            var closeTask = CloseEverything();
    
            await connectionTask;
            await receiveRemoteTask;
    
            var remoteTasks = new List<Task> { connectionTask, receiveRemoteTask, closeTask };
            while (remoteTasks.Count > 0)
            {
                Task finishedTask = await Task.WhenAny(remoteTasks);
                if (finishedTask == connectionTask)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("ConnectionTask finished");
                }
                else if (finishedTask == receiveRemoteTask)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Receive remote Task finished");
                }
                else if (finishedTask == closeTask)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Close Task finished");
                }
                await finishedTask;
                Console.WriteLine($"Task isCompleted state: {IsCompleted}");
    
                await Task.WhenAll(remoteTasks.ToArray());
                // remoteTasks.Remove(finishedTask);
            }
    
            async void SendCallback1(IAsyncResult? sendFirstObject)
            {
                if (sendFirstObject != null)
                {
                    uMaster.EndSend(sendFirstObject);
                    Console.WriteLine("EndSend in SendCallback1 here");
    
                    sendFirstObject.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("sendFirst is null exception. Closing with uMaster.Close.");
                    uMaster.Close();
                }
            }
    
    
            async void ReceiveCallback1(IAsyncResult received)
            {
                if (received != null)
                {
                    byte[] receivedBytes = uMaster.EndReceive(received, ref eMaster!);
                    string receivedString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receivedBytes);
    
                    bool receivedMessageFactory = receivedBytes.Equals(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Please write user name and password, separated with one space and hit enter."));
                    Console.WriteLine($"Received: {receivedString}");
    
                    if (receivedMessageFactory == true)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("received loginRequestMessage from factory. forwarding to LoginRequest");
    
                        uMaster.BeginReceive(ReceiveCallback2, logDataState);
                        Console.WriteLine("Begin ReceiveCallBack 2");
    
                        received.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Wrong factory message received. now uMaster.Close();");
                        uMaster.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
    
            async void ReceiveCallback2(IAsyncResult callBack2Object)
            {
                if (callBack2Object != null)
                {
    
                    byte[] receivedLoginData = uMaster.EndReceive(callBack2Object, ref eMaster!);
                    string loginInfo = receivedLoginData.ToString();
                    Console.WriteLine("receivedLoginData converted to String, comparing next");
    
                    bool loginCheck = loginInfo.Equals(compareLoginData);
    
                    if (receivedLoginData != null)
                    {
                        if (loginCheck == true)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("LoginCheck successful");
                            callBack2Object.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();
                            await ReceiveRemoteReset();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Login Check/compare went wrong. Now uMaster.Close();");
                            uMaster.Close();
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Something went wrong in LoginRequest / comparing. Closing with uMaster.Clsoe()");
                        uMaster.Close();
                    }
                    callBack2Object.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();
                }
            }
    
            async Task ConnectFactory()
            {
                uMaster.Connect(eMaster);
    
                isConnected = true;
    
                uMaster.BeginReceive(ReceiveCallback1, receiveOne);
                Console.WriteLine("First beginReceive");
    
                uMaster.BeginSend(connectMessage, connectMessage.Length, SendCallback1, sendFirst);
                Console.WriteLine("First beginSend");
    
                await ReceiveRemoteReset();
            }
    
            static async Task CloseEverything()
            {
                isConnected = false;
    
                Console.WriteLine("CloseEverything here. Waiting for Task.Delay(200) in same method");
                await Task.Delay(200);
    
                Console.WriteLine("Closing Everything after Delay (ReadKey) for waiting");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
    
            static async Task ReceiveRemoteReset()
            {
                if (isConnected == true)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Waiting Task Delay (600) of ReceiveRemoteReset.)");
                    await Task.Delay(600);
                    Console.WriteLine("Task.Dealy(600) over. CloseEverything()");
                    await CloseEverything();
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("ReceiveRemoteReset, isConnected false CloseEverything()");
                    await CloseEverything();
                }
            }
    
        }
    }

set the ip to fixed ip for now but server should later listen to any ip. Any tips on what is still wrong? (fixed the instanciation new udp clients all the time). the client will listen to it's own message etc.

At the end of the main method add : Console.Readline() so the application doesn't terminate.

thank you, but would it work anyway?

No.  You have a race condition where the application may or may not terminate before the connection is made and data is sent.

okay, thank you. as far as I understand, there is no way to do it with udp, so I receive messages. right?

You need to prevent code from terminating until the message is sent.  Best way is to add a semaphore (WaitOne) to make sure data is sent before closing : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.waithandle.waitone?view=net-8.0

thank you, i thouhgt it would wait in the task lsit for that

I rewrote the code again, learned again a lot but still can'T make the server und client communicate with each other...
server side:

What messages are you getting.  Where does it fail?  Check from cmd.exe >Netstat -a which should show the status of the port number.  Should be showing listening after server is started.

when i run it in visual studio i get the following:
server,  bool login: System.NullReferenceException
Console show it doesn't get a response from client and closes then
client
is almost the same because the client doesnt get a message from the server

Aren't you getting a false here and closing : bool login = receiveLoginDataString.Equals(testData);  What is the trestData?

in server is a string that should be compared named testData for now. plan was to get the bytes from userinput in customer/client, send it to the factory, transform both to strings so it can get compared and then program should resume. at the moment both sides just send everything at the same time and it seems that the await/waitOne aren't working.
edit: just checked and yes, now i get a error message NullReferenceException

You cannot create a constructor inside the constructor's class : GripperUDP start = new GripperUDP();

if i take that out (Main()) i get the error, that there is no main function to start. so i tried to create a instance so it will call the MainAsync()

You can just use : this.MainAsync().Wait();

Should be : public AutoResetEvent cusConnSuccess = new AutoResetEvent(false);

this.MainAsync().Wait(); throws an error.

What is the error?

this: CS0026 static keyword not valid
removing the static in static void main() grey the Main

Remove static.  Static is needed when Main() is used in a console class.  You are creating you own class and main is not needed.  I user class does not need static methods.
